# Grails's yesterday in criteria

Tags: date, grails, criteria

I'm building a criteria to get all yesterday's created records for a certain domain class. Something like

```
def c = A.createCriteria().list {
  eq(<some operation on dateCreated>, <some operation on 'now'>)
}
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about

```
Date today = new Date().clearTime()
Date yesterday = today - 1

def c = A.createCriteria().list {
  ge(yesterday)
  lt(today)
}
```

Comment: should read: 
`Date today = new Date()
today.clearTime()`
good answer though@

Comment: @ekawas It depends on your version of groovy, on newer versions (I think as of 1.8 from memory) clearTime() returns the Date as well. See http://groovy.codehaus.org/groovy-jdk/java/util/Date.html#clearTime%28%29

Answer (score 3):

See example criteria here: http://www.grails.org/doc/1.3.7/ref/Domain%20Classes/withCriteria.html

```
def now = new Date()
between('dateCreated', now-1, now)
```

will get you everything created within 24h of *now*. Just use standard Java date manipulation to set your *now* to midnight.