# Filter date in grails

Tags: grails

In domain i have:
     `int id`
     `Date mydate`

In view:
`<g:datePicker name="mydate" precision="month" default="none"
              noSelection="['':'-Choose-']" years="${2012..2020}"/>`

How i can filter value base on month and year with eq('mydate',session.mydate).

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "filter value base on month and year". Are you trying to filter the dates that the datepicker displays or process the value selected by the user?

Comment: ex: the values in my datebase are 24-MAR-12 09.36.55.006986000 PM, i want to list all values that time in 03/2012.

Answer (score 0):

See [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8603311/grailss-yesterday-in-criteria/8603350#8603350): use a [java.util.Calendar](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html) to create a *startTime* at 01-MAR-2012 00:00:00 and *endTime* 01-APR-2012 00:00:00 and use a *between* criteria.